# React-native debug build for android throwing "pod install" error

Tags: android, react-native, realm

I have been trying to build my Android app using React-NAtive and failing since an error follows,

[image]

My IOS build is successful, but android shows this,
I have installed pods and checked for them.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this package:

`yarn add realm@hermes`

Good luck!